# TensorFlow TextSum decode error: Could not flatten dictionary

Tags: tensorflow, textsum

I try to run [TensorFlow textsum model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/textsum)

Training went well, but when I try to run "decode" mode using toy data provided by authors of the model, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pavel/Sandbox/TensorFlow/textsum/bazel-bin/textsum/seq2seq_attention.runfiles/__main__/textsum/seq2seq_attention.py", line 212, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/pavel/Sandbox/TensorFlow/textsum/bazel-bin/textsum/seq2seq_attention.runfiles/__main__/textsum/seq2seq_attention.py", line 208, in main
    decoder.DecodeLoop()
  File "/home/pavel/Sandbox/TensorFlow/textsum/textsum/seq2seq_attention_decode.py", line 101, in DecodeLoop
    if not self._Decode(self._saver, sess):
  File "/home/pavel/Sandbox/TensorFlow/textsum/textsum/seq2seq_attention_decode.py", line 140, in _Decode
    best_beam = bs.BeamSearch(sess, article_batch_cp, article_lens_cp)[0]
  File "/home/pavel/Sandbox/TensorFlow/textsum/textsum/beam_search.py", line 113, in BeamSearch
    sess, latest_tokens, enc_top_states, states)
  File "/home/pavel/Sandbox/TensorFlow/textsum/textsum/seq2seq_attention_model.py", line 283, in decode_topk
    feed_dict=feed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 864, in _run
    feed_dict = nest.flatten_dict_items(feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 186, in flatten_dict_items
    % (len(flat_i), len(flat_v), flat_i, flat_v))
ValueError: Could not flatten dictionary. Key had 2 elements, but value had 1 elements. Key: [<tf.Tensor 'seq2seq/encoder3/BiRNN/FW/FW/cond_119/Merge_1:0' shape=(8, 256) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'seq2seq/encoder3/BiRNN/FW/FW/cond_119/Merge_2:0' shape=(8, 256) dtype=float32>], value: [array([[[ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        ...,
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227]],

       [[ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        ...,
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227]],

       [[ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        ...,
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227]],

       ...,
       [[ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        ...,
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227]],

       [[ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        ...,
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227]],

       [[ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        ...,
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227],
        [ 2.72009921, -3.38784456, -0.47797373, ...,  0.81595671,
         -6.4550662 ,  5.68320227]]], dtype=float32)].
```

The command I run to do decode:

```
bazel-bin/textsum/seq2seq_attention --mode=decode --article_key=article --abstract_key=abstract --data_path=data/predict --vocab_path=data/vocab --log_root=log_root --decode_dir=log_root/decode --beam_size=8 --truncate_input=True
```

What could be the cause of it?

CUDA 7.5

CUDNN 5.1

TensorFlow 0.10

UPDATE: I tried to install previous version of TensorFlow: 0.9, based on comments on GitHub issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/417 
It helped to resolve the issue.
I still don't know why it doesn't work with version 0.10.

Comment: Just to add a little more to this. The issue seems to be occurring in 0.11 as well.  As per @zxie at the below link, if you set state_is_tuple equal to false in the instantiations of LSTMCell, the issue is resolved.  When I tried this, I did in fact not get the error above, however my results were almost repeating the same thing over and over for different inputs when I ran a decode session. So even though it fixed the error, I am concerned that it really just masks the real issue.  I will update this here should I find anything out.  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/417